# Characterizing compactly assembled localizations of presheaf $\infty$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

After SAG Def 21.1.2.1, say that an $\infty$-category $\mathscr{C}$ is **compactly assembled** if there exists a small $\infty$-category $\mathscr{C}_0$ such that $\mathscr{C}$ is a retract of $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathscr{C}_0)$ in the category $\widehat{\mathsf{Cat}}^\omega$ of large $\infty$-categories and functors that preserve small filtered colimits.

All compactly-generated $\infty$-categories are compactly assembled, but the converse is false.

**Question:** Let $\mathscr{D}$ be a small $\infty$-category, let $S$ be a set of morphisms in $\mathsf{Psh}(\mathscr{D})$, and let $L: \mathsf{Psh}(\mathscr{D}) \to \mathscr{C} := \mathsf{Psh}(\mathscr{D})[S^{-1}]$ denote the localization. Under what conditions on $S$ is $\mathscr{C}$ compactly assembled? I am interested in the case where $\mathscr{C}$ is *not* compactly-generated.

**Question:** Let $\mathscr{D}$ be a small $\infty$-category, let $S$ be a set of morphisms in $\mathsf{Psh}_{\mathsf{Spectra}}(\mathscr{D})$ so that the localization $L: \mathsf{Psh}_{\mathsf{Spectra}}(\mathscr{D}) \to \mathscr{C} := \mathsf{Psh}_{\mathsf{Spectra}}(\mathscr{D})[S^{-1}]$ is an exact localization of stable categories. What are sufficient conditions on $L$ so that $\mathscr{C}$ is compactly-assembled?

Comment: I'm not sure of the best example to have in mind of a compactly-assembled (=presentable [continuous](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/continuous+category)) but not compactly-generated category. Maybe sheaves on a manifold? For instance, is there an illuminating presentation of $Sh([0,1])$ or $Sh(\mathbb R)$ as a localization of a presheaf category?

Comment: An example in a reasonably general setting of a continuous category constructed as a localization of a presheaf category is given in [Johnstone-Joyal](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(82)90083-4) -- see Thm 4.10, and work backwards through the paper for references to the topology $J_T$ discussed there. [Anel and Lejay](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.10425) treats similar material in an $\infty$-categorical setting, but I don't recall how "localization-theoretic" their treatment is.

Comment: @TimCampion I am extremely skeptical about your argument. How did you use the adjoint functor theorem? You did not prove that $M$ preserves (infinite) limits, I think. In fact, a presentable stable $\infty$-category is compactly assembled if and only if it is dualizable (SAG D.7.3.1). Although I don't have concrete examples, I believe that not everything is dualizable.

Comment: The definition of compactly assembled gives two different sufficient conditions: 1) the right adjoint of $L$ preserves filtered colimits (but in this case $C$ is even compactly generated), 2) $L$ itself preserves limits.

Comment: @Z.M Thanks, I've deleted that boneheaded comment

Comment: @MarcHoyois thanks. I've added as a follow-up question the analogous situation but for stable categories.

Comment: @Z.M : dualizable categories are not compact in $Pr^L_{st}$ ( in fact, I doubt that there exists a single nontrivial compact object in $Pr^L_{st}$ - $Sp$ certainly isn't).

Comment: @MaximeRamzi So $\operatorname{Pr}^L$ is compact (I heard once, and seemingly generated by $\operatorname{An}$ and presheaves on an edge), but the stable one is not?

Comment: @Z.M : $Pr^L$ is not compactly generated, no. It is generated by $An^{\Delta^1}$ under colimits , but neither $An^{\Delta^1}$ nor $An$ are compact. A filtered colimit in $Pr^L$ gives an inverse limit of $map(An,-)$'s (as an example, look at what happens with infinite coproducts)

Comment: @TimCampion My argument was incorrect. Removed. See above comment by Maxime.